# How to center an image in Azure DevOps

Tags: html, azure-devops, yaml

I uploaded an image as attachment in my wiki page... here the code generated to the page:

```
![myImage.png](/.attachments/MyImage_3-dc7eb2d3-c632-4fe3-831a-b5dbfcbf1d98.png)
```

I would like to center this image. But I cannot.

I tried to wrap that YAML code inside an HTML div.. but it's like i cannot insert YAML tags inside HTML tag...

I also tried to add the `style` tag, but `style` tag is not supported in Azure devOps Wiki pages.

Finally I tried to add a HTML `img` tag instead of yaml, but it does not recognize therelative path of the uploaded image...

Does a way to center the image exist?

Thank you

Comment: Can you accept the most upvoted answer?

Answer (score 11):

### **Nowadays**

Based on the answer of [rickvdbosch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54022553/468910) it can be done simply with:

```
<center>

![image.png](/.attachments/image-b2195f3b-f3af-467b-b9d6-0853b1cd7d08.png)

</center>
```

Without the need of a blob storage in Azure but just with the relative path created by Azure DevOps when inserting the image.

Steps:

1. Copy paste an image in the wiki editor / markdown, or use the insert file menu command
2. Put the `<center>` tags around it
3. Add some padding or other styling to the `<center>` tag

Comment: Good solution. Please note the blank line after <center>. Otherwise it does not work.

Comment: This is it - and can be generalized. In my case, I used <div style="float: right">.

Answer (score 1):

Figure out the entire path (or the *right* relative one) for the image and put it in an `img`-tag inside a `<center>` tag. When inserting a file in a Wiki, I get an image-url like `blob:https://dev.azure.com/SOME-GUID`. This url (when **including** the `blob:`-prefix, can be used to display the attached image in an `img`-tag.

```
<center>
    <img src="blob:https://dev.azure.com/SOME-GUID" />
</center>
```

[image: Centered image in Azure DevOps Wiki]

If the image is important enough to be inside a Wiki page, it's probably important enough to host it somewhere you can use it inside your wiki. Have a look at creating a [public container/blob in an Azure Storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources).

**EDIT:**
I *have* migrated my Organization to "Use the new URL: https://dev.azure.com/MY-ORGANIZATION/" (from Organization Settings - Overview). This might have impact on the way attached files are uploaded, although a different organization I'm in *hasn't* upgraded to the new URL yet, and also gets a decent `blob:blob:https://dev.azure.com/SOME-GUID` url for attached files.

Comment: I am not sure about this solution, because the absolute path is really strange... `https://mytfs.visualstudio.com/96559a72-7481-4df1-b007-a026aae9c06b/_apis/git/repositories/34a0b44d-094a-4a84-833b-9464bf081bb0/Items?path=%2F.attachments%2FMyImage_3-dc7eb2d3-c632-4fe3-831a-b5dbfcbf1d98.png&versionDescriptor%5BversionOptions%5D=0&versionDescriptor%5BversionType%5D=0&versionDescriptor%5Bversion%5D=wikiMaster&download=false&resolveLfs=true&%24format=octetStream&api-version=5.0-preview.1` ... I dont know what could happen if Microsoft decide to change something... I think it is not a remote idea.

Comment: if I remove just a value from querystring, for example a "*version", nothing works anymore... but, hey.... the solution works...

Comment: They probably won't change this url anyhow... But is this an image that is attached to a workitem? Because if it's directly under a repo the url can be a LOT simpler.

Comment: No, it is uploaded as attachment of the wikipage

Comment: Thank you... it works now.. I had to migrate using new url, I then I uploaded again the image

Comment: No... I am sorry... it does not work.... it seems like this kind of url `blob:https://dev.azure.com/SOME-GUID` is temporary... but after some minutes it get changed... and get back how I posted before